# Is the Devil actually at work in Ohio?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-devil-in-ohio

In the first few episodes of the miniseries *The Devil in Ohio*, we see a few signs that could be supernatural: for instance, a crow crashed into the window of the Mathis family's house, seemingly spurred by May's presence (but that could just be coincidence). Perhaps more obviously, when Mae and Suzanne were visiting a foster family to see if they would be a good fit for Mae, a cross on the wall behind Mae seemingly spontaneously flipped over (but I suppose that it is *possible* that she quickly flipped it over "off-camera").

However, for the rest of the show, there is nary a whisper of supernatural forces, except for the cult leader talking to a crow, which could mean anything. Certainly, the cult displays no demonic powers, and their successful ritual at the end does not seem to produce any results.

Are there actually any overt demonic or supernatural forces at play? Or is everything simply the work of a Luciferian cult that is no more or less mundane than any other sect?

Comment: I guess it's one of these "maybe need to watch more episodes to see if they tell us" situations? Meaning it's ambiguous for now on purpose...

Comment: @Luciano - It's labeled as a miniseries in Netflix, so it appears that it is planned for one season? Normally the ones that are planned for (possibly) multiple seasons are labeled "series."

Answer (score 1):

After watching the entire series it doesn't seem (to me) that the actual devil or a literal demon is at work in Ohio. The only supernatural-looking events are the ones you mention, and could be easily explained (cross: she turned herself when no one was looking; crow hits the window: coincidence; leader talking to crow: maybe in his mind?).

However...

Perhaps the series title is an allusion to the character Mae. In the beginning she is shown as a victim, but as the series progresses we see her manipulating people for her own purposes in several occasions.

- she seems to be getting along with Jules and doing things to help her, but she's gaining popularity to the point where the whole school thinks of her as some sort of hero
- she goes out to the dance with Helen's boyfriend as soon as they broke up - and win the Harvest Queen title
- she pretends to get triggered by the white flowers during Harvest Queen coronation, but she replaced the original flowers herself
- ultimately driving the family apart so she ended up with Suzanne all for herself...